# mod_rewrite mask folder name

Tags: php, sql, mod-rewrite, directory, mask

Looking to do the following:

`domain.com` - root directly with unique files that are different than individual cities.

`domain.com/city_name` - this folder will have CMS elements and individual content based on the city the user ends up at.

Ultimately, all files to control the CMS will be in `/city_name` but I page a file called pageLoader.php?page=$1 so I can do a `$_GET[''];` and request the name of the city they've entered, example: `domain.com/vancouver`

So, what I need to do is "mask" the city_name folder with

```
/vancouver, /los-angeles etc...
```

Is this possible? How would I go about doing this.

ANY RESPONSE IS SUPER HELPFUL on a deadline for a project and having difficulties figuring this out.

Thanks.

EDIT: basically need to read the /city_name folder when someone types in /vancouver

Answer (score 1):

First, are you using Apache or IIS? Anyway I guess you can do the following...

In the .htaccess (Apache):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) -d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

In the web.config (IIS)

```
<rule name="rewrite" stopProcessing="true" >
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="%(REQUEST_FILENAME)" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: That does not work. Basically think the website is in a folder called /city_name that's literally where all of the files for cities will be helt. profile.php, user-list.php, etc... But I need the folder /city_name to be masked with the actual city itself. /city_name is a physical folder, where /vancouver would be a virtual folder but will be reading all the code/content from the files controlling it in /city_name

Comment: Ahh ok!, I haven't understood the question, well I guess I can't help you with that problem. If I found something, I'll tell you @Jordie.