# Apache mod_rewrite wont read from folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /city_name

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /city_name/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So I have this working so that if I do `domain.com/calgary/` it will read from the database properly.

But if I do `domain.com/calgary/test.php` that folder is not reading properly because it thinks that the files are in `/calgary/` even though it's a virtual directory.

So I am looking for help probably in the `.htaccess` directory in the `/city_name/` folder so that it will read files with `.php` from the `/city_name/` directory instead of `/calgary/` (the virtual)

Comment: What should `domain.com/calgary/test.php` be rewritten to?

Comment: I want the address to start domain.com/calgary/test.php but test.php will exist in domain.com/city_name/ which holds all the city files which are dynamically generated by the /calgary/ (or as City ID) @zerkms

Comment: Well, what exact address should `domain.com/calgary/test.php` be rewritten to?! `mod_rewrite` does nothing but just dummy rewrite of one string to another

Comment: /calgary/ is ACTUALLY /city_name/ so i need the browser to think like it's /calgary/ in terms of URL wise, but the server to read the files from /city_name/

Comment: is it that difficult to just show url which `domain.com/calgary/test.php` should be rewritten to? Without further explanations, just plain url, nothing else

Comment: I GO TO: domain.com/calgary/test.php --the server reads this-- domain.com/city_name/test.php -- problem is is that domain.com/calgary/ isnt a physical folder on the server so the server is looking for a folder called calgary i need it to now look for /city_name/ back in that directory. perhaps mod_rewrite isnt the best method for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567187/mod-rewrite-mask-folder-name is a post i had earlier. this may help explain what im trying to do a bit better.

Comment: it's not possible to help you when you don't want our help. The only thing we need to know - is what it should be rewritten to. One hour passed and you still explaining something instead of giving just a simple answer. Sighs...

Comment: Sorry I certainly want your help I just don't think I'm understanding your question properly.

Comment: what `mod_rewrite` does is just rewrites input url to something else. Nothing more. So you request `domain.com/calgary/test.php` and what do you want it to be rewritten to? Which script should handle such request? (please reply with just a single url, without explanations (they only make things worse))

Comment: i visit domain.com/calgary/test.php server needs to read this folder/file domain.com/city_reader/test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^\./]+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/city_name/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\./]+)\.php$ /city_name/$2.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /calgary/test-page.php was not found on this server. However when I just do /calgary/ it'll spit out the city details for me.

Comment: @Jordie Does the file `/city_name/test-page.php` exist? That's what this line checks: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/city_name/%1.php -f` and the condition fails if there is no `/city_name/test-page.php` in the server's document root. (Note that it may not work if it's a test-page.php is a symlink).

Comment: Yes /city_name/test-page.php exists. It is that folder. However, remember that *city_name* is a masked folder right. Users should never see *city_name* rather they'd see *calgary*/my-profile.php. But the server is looking for the file my-profile.php or test-page.php in the *calgary* folder. So need a way to kind of redirect without losing the *calgary* folder. Does that make sense? My .htaccess file in / directory has the above code. Your example, would I be placing it below my above code/replacing my above or would I place that in the /city_name/ folder. (mod_rewrite beginner)

Comment: @Jordie It makes sense, and when I create a directory tree for `city_name` and some test php files on my apache test box, and put those rewrite rules in a blank htaccess file in the document root, that is exactly how everything behaves. I go to `/calgary/test.php` and my browser's address bar is unchanged, but I get served the file that is in `/city_name/test.php?page=calgary`.

Comment: Hi Jon yes, I have the directory itself working /city_name/ so I go domain.com/calgary and it works... But as soon as I look for a file such as doamin.com/calgary/test.php it returns a document not found.

Comment: So you have lets say /http_docs/.htaccess running the rules you gave me above. You then have a folder /http_docs/city_name/ which is what is being rewritten right now, and within /http_docs/city_name/ you have test.php and it seems to work for you?

Comment: Ultimately, / will have its own static data, the reason I'm placing all dynamic data including user profiles etc in /city_name is for organizational skills and really am unsure how else to do it. A one to many model so we have SEO benefits as well as one version does all. I update /city_name/profile.php with new validations, and it's changed across 30 other cities as well because they all run off 1 file.

Comment: @Jordie Yes, it works for me. However, I don't have the rules that you previously had. The index.php rules will need to be reworked, probably to continue working.

Comment: @Jordie I take that back, I added these rules to the end of your original rules, put them in the document root, and it all works fine. See screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4N63v.png The right window is the htaccess file, the left window is a transcript of me sending GET requests to apache.

Comment: Awesome I will try this and let you know shortly. Thank you kindly Jon for your help! Very much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Jon - so it's working but any URL with a ? in it, for instance /calgary/dashboard.php?step=change-password doesn't work. It's not reading anything after the ? ... I've tried fixing this but with no luck. Any advice?